# What should my vertex shader look like if I am rendering two different objects?

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to use two different VAOs and VBOs to render two different objects. If I were to render these two objects, I followed this code:

`render()` part:

```
// some uniform variables to change my first object

glBindVertexArray(vao1);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indicesNo1);


// some uniform variables to change my second object

glBindVertexArray(vao2);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, indicesNo2);
```

But I have no idea how should my vertex shader look like since I have a different PNG texture to render for my first object and another PNG for my second object. I tried using this `main()` code for my `.vs` but only my second object showed up:

`main()`:

```
// FOR TRUCK (my first object)


worldSpacePosition = (model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0f)).xyz;
worldSpaceNormal = (normal_matrix * vec4(vertexNormal, 1.0f)).xyz;
objectColor = vertexColor;
shaderTexCoord = vertexTexCoord;
gl_Position = (projection_view_matrix) * vec4(worldSpacePosition, 1.0f);



// FOR MOTORCYCLE (my second object)

worldSpacePositionMotorcycle = (model_matrix_motorcycle * vec4(vertexPositionMotorcycle, 1.0f)).xyz;
worldSpaceNormalMotorcycle = (normal_matrix_motorcycle * vec4(vertexNormalMotorcycle, 1.0f)).xyz;
objectColorMotorcycle = vertexColorMotorcycle;
shaderTexCoordMotorcycle = vertexTexCoordMotorcycle;
gl_Position = (projection_view_matrix_motorcycle) * vec4(worldSpacePositionMotorcycle, 1.0f);
```

I know I shouldn't use `gl_Position` twice... how should I do this?

One thing I know though, I got to draw an object three times using `glDrawArraysInstanced` (with only 1 VAO and VBO) but I have `gl_InstanceID` to use in the vertex shader. What about when using `glDrawArrays` twice? How do I show them in the `.vs` since I cant use `gl_InstanceID`?

Comment: You can use the same shader program for all your objects. Just change the uniforms and texture bindings before you drawing a specific object. I recommend reading a good OpenGL tutorial, e.g.: [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/)

Comment: The object is rendered according to all the current data - the vertex shader, the fragment shader, the vertex data, the textures, etc. Do you need a different vertex shader for the second object or don't you?

Comment: @user253751 Hello! I don't need to use a different vertex shader. Does that mean I dont need to use two sets of the code above (in `main`)?

Comment: If you don't need to use a different vertex shader then you don't need to use a different vertex shader. I'm not sure which code you're specifically talking about

Comment: In case you are confused, a shader does not run all the time in the background or anything. It runs separately for every vertex.